# extjs3.4 gridpanel rowselect event not working

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid

I have a grid panel, I am using ExtJS 3.4 . I want to select a row and then when I click the update button, the values of the row selected has to be populated in a window. I tried using the rowselect and rowclick event, but both of it did not work. Can someone tell me how to do this.

Also,how to align the paging toolbar to the bottom of the screen?

```
this.grid= new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
                    layout: 'fit',
                    //autoHeight: true,
                    height: 556,
                    store: store,
                    columns:[
                           {header: "Book Name", dataIndex: 'bookName'},
                           {header: "Author Name", dataIndex: 'authorName'}
                           ],
                    sm: new Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel({singleSelect: true}),
                    bbar: new Ext.PagingToolbar({
                           store: store,  // grid and PagingToolbar using same store
                           displayInfo: true,
                           pageSize: pgSize
                        }),
                    listeners:{
                        'rowselect': function(){ 
                                alert("Here");
                        } 
                    }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use getSelectionModel function to get the reference of grid's selected row

Sample fiddle here: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/e5l

also [bbar](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.GridPanel-cfg-bbar) config should display toolbar at the bottom of the panel, not sure what problem you are facing..

Comment: sorry for late reply..that helped..thanx :)bbar config depends on d layout of parent container, so that was d problem..